# What problems won't I put up with with you?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Just an interesting sentence. I want to know if it's compeletely alright for using and constructing this way:

> What problems won't I put up with with you?

Comment: *This is a dangerous neighbourhood, where you need to watch out out on the streets after dark.* *I hate hearing pundits witter on on TV.* Not necessarily "elegant", but people say things like this all the time.

Comment: How will it be different for:
"his is a dangerous neighbourhood, where you need to watch out in the streets after dark."
Will it be any different?
What is "pundits witter"?

Comment: The basic structure is ***X is Y***, where syntactically both ***X*** and ***Y*** function as nouns - it makes no difference whether ***X*** is ***This, That, His, Theirs, Harlem,*** or whatever. ***Pundits*** are "opinionated commentators" (often, as in my usage, a *derogatory* reference). To ***witter on*** is always derogatory, meaning ***to talk for a long time about things that are not important - to prattle, prate, babble, etc.***

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
But also I meant "watch out in the streets " insted of "watch out out on the streets"

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. They both mean the same, they're both syntactically fine, and *they both feature repeated prepositions*, which isn't a problem in English. But both myself and @Lorel below are obviously assuming that's what's bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely OK. If you are talking about the double "with", it is just like FumbleFingers says: that happens sometimes. Two expressions have a common word, and they collide.

If you are talking about the unusual construction of the negative (rhetorical) question, that's OK too.

Comment: unusual construction of the negative (rhetorical) question?
What do you mean by that?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko: Your example is a "negative (rhetorical) question". Same as, for example, ***It's so hot! What wouldn't I give for a cold Coke?*** Where nobody seriously thinks you'd be expecting an "answer" to your (phrased in the negative) "question".

Comment: Why rhetorical? "What problems won't I put up with with you?" can be like "What problems won't I endure with you"? It can be a situation when I really need some answer for this

Comment: Do you mean you think this could be interpreted as a real question that someone else would be expected to answer? Only the asker would really know, and it's hard to imagine a possible answer to a question like that anyway. Thinking up a list of all the problems you won't tolerate could be difficult. Sort of like trying to find out how many accidents didn't happen in the workplace that day. As they say, it's limited only by your imagination.

Comment: But look. it can be like" A: Thank you for coming to help me here B: You are welcome but you should know you won't be able to solve some of the matters even with my help A: "What problems won't I put up with with you?"

Comment: If the conv. went like that (using "put up with"), A's last remark is a non-sequitur, & also rude & passive-aggressive. The expression, "to put up with [s/t annoying]" means, "to tolerate [it]", and here it sounds like B is creating problems for A, & A is getting mad. In this convers'n, it almost sounds like you're using "put up with" as "to be able to solve [something]". Are you perhaps thinking of the expression "to *deal* with or "*cope* with"?..."What problems won't I *cope* with with you?" sounds a littl contrived, but not *imposs*. "... *be able to* cope with with ..." mayb a littl bettr